# Add dynamic discount value in custom discount section html file Magento 2

Tags: magento2, model, discount

I have created the module for the custom discount from https://www.mageplaza.com/how-add-custom-discount-magento-2.html. But there is a static value '$10'in customdiscount.html file.I want to add the dynamic value in that file or similar to value **$baseDiscount** from 'Custom.php'. Please help me if anyone knows that how can I add the dynamic amount as a discount?
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Please try with https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/219082/how-to-set-discount-value-in-js-file-magento2/236033#236033 and https://webkul.com/blog/set-custom-discount-fee-cart-magento-2/