# How to set discount value in .js file magento2

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I have followed 
https://webkul.com/blog/set-custom-discount-fee-cart-magento-2/
to get dynamic value. I tried below code.

```
define(
  [
      'jquery',
       'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total',
       'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
       'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils',
       'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals'
  ],
  function ($,Component, quote, priceUtils, totals) {
      "use strict";
      return Component.extend({
          defaults: {
              template: 'Mp_Accountmanager/checkout/summary/customdiscount'
          },
          total_tmp: quote.getTotals(),
          isTaxDisplayedInGrandTotal: window.checkoutConfig.includeTaxInGrandTotal || false,
          isDisplayedCustomdiscount : function(){
              return true;
          },
          getCustomDiscount : function(){
              return total_tmp.getSegment('coupondiscount_total').value;
          }
      });
  }
);
```

but i cannot set the value please help someone to solve this issue and can  anybody know how to get quote value in .js file

Comment: Don't understand,Where you want to achieve  this.

Comment: on cart page i want to display discount which i set in .phtml file @AmitBera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code

```
define(
  [
      'jquery',
       'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total',
       'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
       'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils',
       'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals'
  ],
  function ($,Component, quote, priceUtils, totals) {
      "use strict";
      return Component.extend({
          defaults: {
              template: 'Mp_Accountmanager/checkout/summary/customdiscount'
          },
          total_tmp: quote.getTotals(),
          isTaxDisplayedInGrandTotal: window.checkoutConfig.includeTaxInGrandTotal || false,
          isDisplayedCustomdiscount : function(){
              return true;
          },
          getCustomDiscount : function(){
              return this.getFormattedPrice(total_tmp.getSegment('coupondiscount_total').value);
          }
      });
  }
);
```

Comment: Can you explain               return this.getFormattedPrice(total_tmp.getSegment('coupondiscount_total').value);

Comment: This will return the coupon price total_tmp.getSegment('coupondiscount_total').value and this.getFormattedPrice() is use for formatting the price value it add the currency symbol